# Should I have a Guru Badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

It's been several days now - should I have earned a Guru badge for: [Co-worker renamed all of my queries](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/90561/co-worker-renamed-all-of-my-queries/90566#90566)
?
It's not the answer with the highest vote count, but I didn't see that as a requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep you *should* have the badge, but due to a bug in that particular case, it wasn't being granted.  You cannot get guru for your *own* answer (since that easily bypasses the accepted part of the requirement).

In the SQL there was a check for this:

```
 And accepted.OwnerUserId <> p.OwnerUserId
```

...and in SQL Server, when `p.OwnerUserId` is `null` (the owner of the question was deleted), well...that check of course doesn't work so well.

It's been properly `IsNull()`'d in the next build, once that goes out we'll properly grant the Guru badges in the deleted-owner case.

Comment: Been there, done that, got the bug report.  Thanks!